# Modularize classes with similar lambda expressions

Tags: c++, inheritance, lambda

I have a Interface and 2 child classes from it:

```
class meteo_sanity {
public:
    virtual raster_inserter::core::Raster
    operator()(const raster_inserter::core::Raster& raster) = 0;
    meteo_sanity(raster_inserter::core::Synth_builder& synth_table){};
protected:
    double mean = 0.0;
    double mean_squared = 0.0;
    int n = 0;
};
class meteo_sanity_check_hum_vera: public meteo_sanity {
public:
    using meteo_sanity::meteo_sanity;
    raster_inserter::core::Raster
    operator()(const raster_inserter::core::Raster& raster);
};

class meteo_sanity_check_ff_vera: public meteo_sanity {
public:
    using meteo_sanity::meteo_sanity;
    raster_inserter::core::Raster
    operator()(const raster_inserter::core::Raster& raster);
};
```

Each implementation of `operator()` in both childs are very similar but still I cannot find a way to modularize more my current approach:

```
Raster meteo_sanity_check_hum_vera::operator()(const Raster& raster) {

    double constexpr alpha {0.0002}; // a0
    double constexpr beta {0.5};     // a1
    double constexpr gamma {0.001};  // k
    double constexpr a2 {400};
    double constexpr a3 {-100000};

    auto min_max_check = [&](Matrix_index i) {

        double val = raster[i];

        if (val < gamma){
            if (val <= 0.0) val = alpha * exp(beta * val / alpha);
            else val = alpha + val * (beta + val * (a2 + a3 * val));
        }

        assert_value_in_range("values", val, 0.0, 0.05);
        mean += val;
        mean_squared += val * val;
        n++;
    };

    For_each(raster).tlyx(min_max_check);
    mean /= n;
    mean_squared /= n;

    assert_value_in_range("stddev", sqrt(mean_squared - mean * mean),
                          0.001, std::numeric_limits<double>::max());
    return raster.shallow_copy();
}

Raster meteo_sanity_check_ff_vera::operator()(const Raster& raster) {

    static const double eta = 0.1;
    static const double zeta = 0.2;
    static const double k = 0.5;
    static const double a0 = eta;
    static const double a1 = zeta;
    static const double a2 = 2.0;
    static const double a3 = -1.6;

    auto min_max_check = [&](Matrix_index i) {

        double val = raster[i];

        if(val<k){
            if (val <= 0) {
                 val = eta * exp(zeta * val / eta);
             } else {
                 val = a0 + a1 * val + a2 * val * val + a3 * val * val * val;
             }
        }
        assert_value_in_range("values", val, 0, 120.0);
        mean += val;
        mean_squared += val * val;
        n++;
    };

    For_each(raster).tlyx(min_max_check);
    mean /= n;
    mean_squared /= n;

    assert_value_in_range("stddev", sqrt(mean_squared - mean * mean),
                          0.1, std::numeric_limits<double>::max());
    return raster.shallow_copy();
}
```

The lambda functions are almost identical and even some of the variables could be generalized as well but I cannot find a suitable way to do it.

Comment: As far as I can see, the entire `operator()`s are identical except for the values (and names) of the constants.

Comment: Inside the if clauses the structure is different

Comment: @HectorEsteban Not quite, a + b * x + c * x * x + d * x * x * x = a + x * (b + x * (c + d * x))

Comment: The conditionals only use different names, and one is using Horner's rule in order to do fewer multiplications for the same result. Replace alpha/beta and eta/zeta with a0 and a1 and you get the same code.

Comment: But the lambdas get the parameters from the function they are in, how could I share a lambda between both classes?

Comment: @HectorEsteban If you extract (and rename) the constants to a struct,  you only need one class, with the constants struct as a member. Pass it on construction and create two instances instead of two subclasses.

Comment: And to initilize the struct for each of the current classes how could I make it constant without having to pass it as parameter?